# Creating a random 4 digit number, and storing it to a string

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a method which generates a 4 digit integer and stores it in a string.
The 4 digit integer must lie between 1000 and below 10000. Then the value must be stored to `PINString`.
Heres what I have so far. I get the error `Cannot invoke toString(String) on the primitive type int`. How can I fix it?

```
   public void generatePIN() 
   {

        //generate a 4 digit integer 1000 <10000
        int randomPIN = (int)(Math.random()*9000)+1000;

        //Store integer in a string
        randomPIN.toString(PINString);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you want it higher than 1000. I think that 0050 is a valid number (though looks strange).

Comment: obviously not an exact duplicate but it's the same problem with the same solution...so.

Comment: For those seeking to generate OTP Pins that could have values like 0004, 0032 or 0516. Here is the code.   `Random random = new Random();
String generatePin = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(10000));
        System.out.println(generatePin);`

Comment: Here is another way.   `Random random = new Random();
String generatePin = String.format("%04d",  random.nextInt(10000000) % 10000);
        System.out.println(generatePin);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use `PINString = String.valueOf(randomPIN);`

Answer (score 10):

Make a String variable, concat the generated int value in it:

```
int randomPIN = (int)(Math.random()*9000)+1000;
String val = ""+randomPIN;
```

OR even more simple

```
String val = ""+((int)(Math.random()*9000)+1000);
```

Can't get any more simple than this ;)

Answer (score 2):

`randomPIN` is a primitive datatype.

If you want to store the integer value in a `String`, use [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29):

```
String pin = String.valueOf(randomPIN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a string to store the value:

```
   String PINString= String.valueOf(randomPIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. The x is just the first digit. It is from 1 to 9.
Then you append it to another number which has at most 3 digits.

```
public String generatePIN() 
{   
    int x = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
    x = x + 1;
    String randomPIN = (x + "") + ( ((int)(Math.random()*1000)) + "" );
    return randomPIN;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `(int)(Math.random()*9000)+1000;` ?

Comment: Nothing, I think. I misunderstood what the question was about. I thought it was about the number generation formula itself.